# $O(3)$ sigma model for lumps

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, solitons

I'm studying the $O(3)$ $\sigma$-model related to lumps through chapter 6 of Manton's book.

There appears that $$\mathcal{L}  = (1/4)\partial _{\mu}\phi \cdot \partial ^{\mu}\phi + \nu (1-\phi \cdot \phi)$$ (note: where $\phi = (\phi _{1},\phi _{2},\phi _{3})$ and the model is in (d+1) dimensional Minkowski space-time) and that the resulting E-L equation is, after eliminating $\nu$, $\partial _{\mu}\partial ^{\mu}\phi + (\partial _{\mu}\phi \cdot \partial ^{\mu}\phi)$ $\phi$ = 0. Could someone derive the expression for $\nu$ please? I'm seriously stuck on it.

On the other hand, where is derived $(\partial _{i}\phi \pm \epsilon _{ij}\phi \times \partial_{j}\phi) \cdot (\partial _{i}\phi \pm \epsilon _{ik}\phi \times \partial_{k}\phi) > 0$ from?

Comment: How can you add $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi$ to an $O(3)$ scalar?

Comment: Manton argues that he parametrize the field as a 3-component unit vector $\textbf{\phi}$ = $(\phi _{1}, \phi _{2}, \phi _{3})$

Comment: Yes so $\partial_\mu \phi \cdot \partial^\mu \phi$ is a scalar and your equation does not make sense.

Comment: If you are telling me about the E-L equations I noticed a mistake and I have just corrected, I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal L = \frac 1 4 \partial_\mu\vec \phi \cdot \partial^\mu\vec \phi + \nu(1 - \vec \phi \cdot \vec \phi),
$$
where $\vec \phi = (\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3)^T$ is the $O(3)$ triplet and $\nu$ is a Lagrange-multiplier to fix the constraint $|\vec\phi| = 1$.
Using the EL-equation we arrive at
$$
\frac 1 2 \partial_\mu\partial^\mu \vec\phi +2\nu\vec\phi = 0.
\implies \nu = -\frac 1 4 \partial_\mu\partial^\mu \vec\phi \cdot \vec\phi
$$
From $|\vec\phi| = 1$ we know (by repeated differentiation)
$$
0 = \partial_\mu \vec\phi \cdot \vec\phi + \vec\phi \cdot\partial_\mu  \vec\phi
\implies 2 \partial_\mu \partial^\mu\vec\phi \cdot \vec\phi  + 2\partial_\mu\vec \phi \cdot \partial^\mu\vec \phi= 0
$$
$$
\partial_\mu \partial^\mu\vec\phi \cdot \vec\phi = -\partial_\mu\vec \phi \cdot \partial^\mu\vec \phi.
$$
So inserting the above into $\nu$
$$
\nu = \frac 1 4 \partial_\mu\vec \phi \cdot \partial^\mu\vec \phi
$$
and $\nu$ into the EoM
$$
\frac 1 2 \partial_\mu\partial^\mu \vec\phi + \frac 2 4 (\partial_\mu\vec \phi \cdot \partial^\mu\vec \phi  )\vec\phi = 0.
$$
which results in
$$
\partial_\mu\partial^\mu \vec\phi + (\partial_\mu\vec \phi \cdot \partial^\mu\vec \phi  )\vec\phi = 0.
$$
The full answer to your second question is given in the answer by mike stone.

Comment: You are marvellous!!! Thank you so much!! Your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The field $\nu(x,t) $ is a Lagrange multiplier enforcing the constraint ${\boldsymbol \phi}\cdot \boldsymbol \phi=1$. It takes whatever value it needs to do this. To find an expression for it, first find the EL equation for $\boldsymbol\phi$ including an arbitrary $\nu(x,t) $ Take the dot product with ${\boldsymbol \phi}$, use ${\boldsymbol \phi}\cdot \boldsymbol \phi=1$, and read off   the expression for $\nu $.

As for your last question: the dot product of any real three vector with itself is $\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! It was great.